# To know IIS version

Tags: iis

Trying to understand which version of IIS I have in my system. It is version 6.2 or 8.5 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Versions of Internet Information Server (IIS)]

This contains a table of all versions of IIS.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224609

Answer (score 0):

Internet Information Service(Version 8.5.XXX)

so the IIS version is 8.5

Answer (score 0):

It means that IIS version is 8.5.9600.16384 and 6.2 is your Windows version.

Because it is Windows 8. The version is 6.2. If windows 7, version will be 6.1.

Answer (score -1):

A FAR easier way to tell what version of IIS you are running:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -name "Web-Mgmt-Console"|select *
```